# XStream fromXML with dynamic inner structure

Tags: xml-parsing, xstream

I have XML object that I want converted back into the objects but am having trouble doing it with XStream.  The problem with it is that the "RESULT" tag is different from different API services, so not sure how to alias it for different classes.  The example below would be for a LOGIN service example.  I may have another service that has the same Envelope/Body/RESULT/ but different attributes within it, i.e. Logout.  Not sure how to go about leveraging the Envelope and Body to reduce redundent code.

```
<Envelope>
<Body>
    <RESULT>
<SUCCESS>true</SUCCESS>
<SESSIONID>1320948a32098</SESSIONID>
<ORGANIZATION_ID>1</ORGANIZATION_ID>
</RESULT>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

I have currently created classes for EnvelopeResponse, BodyResponse and a ResultResponse class I'll want all my other classes extending from? Is that the way to go about it?  i.e. My LoginResponse class extends from ResultResponse.class, same for LogoutResponse.

I tried

```
xStream = new Xstream();
xStream.alias("Envelope", EnvelopeResponse.class);
xStream.alias("Body", BodyResponse.class);
xStream.alias("RESULT", LoginResponse.class); //Dynamic based on what API I'd like in the RESULT
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are having multiple services, adding one more level of abstraction would be a good idea.

i.e.

```
<Envelope>
<Body>
    <RESULT>
     <LOGINRESPONSE>
       <SUCCESS>true</SUCCESS>
       <SESSIONID>1320948a32098</SESSIONID>
       <ORGANIZATION_ID>1</ORGANIZATION_ID>
     </LOGINRESPONSE>
   </RESULT>
</Body>
</Envelope>

<Envelope>
<Body>
    <RESULT>
     <LOGOUT>
       <SUCCESS>true</SUCCESS>
     </LOGOUT>
   </RESULT>
</Body>
</Envelope>
```

You can then alias these service responses to different classes,

```
xStream.alias("LOGOUT", LOGOUT.class);

xStream.alias("LOGINRESPONSE", LOGINRESPONSE.class);
```